# How to get expected url

Tags: php, twitter

I have developed a website, using Twitter API. Now a little but important problem I am facing is expected URL.
There will be users on my site who are going to get details with their user name.

My site url right now is : www.mysite.com/
It also works on : www.mysite.com/home.php
and : www.mysite.com/FinalShow01.php

Now what I want is user should be searched when he enter his name as : www.mysite.com/username

I tried this thing on server cpanel, but could not get it done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, what you need to do is make `/person_name` a parameter to be passed to your front page (ie a restful version of `/?name=person_name`). You don't say what web app framework you are using (if any) but your framework should allow you to do this. If no framework you could roll your own easily enough.

Comment: Thank you Richard for your quick response, will try on it.

Comment: Sure no probs. Note that this approach means you'll have to handle requests to other site resources: e.g you may have content (pages) under /about for eaxmple which you don't want to pass as a name parameter. Again your framework should allow you to set up url filters.

Comment: just working on it. not yet solved. I am not using any framework. just devoloped using php(5.2.6) and Mysql.